# Can't figure out what lazy-loading policy NHibernate uses

Tags: nhibernate, lazy-loading

Can somebody tell me what lazy-loading policy NHibernate uses? Various sources provides contradictory information - [this one](http://web.archive.org/web/20100711074950/http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/11/17/lazy-loading-blobs-and-the-like-in-nhibernate.aspx?) says that NHibernate doesn't provide lazy-loading for properties, and NHibernate in Action read that lazy-fetching are on by default. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not an expert but I think that the book means lazy loading of collection properties. As for other properties nhibernate does support them but it might not be released yet:  [NHibernate new feature: Lazy Properties](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/01/27/nhibernate-new-feature-lazy-properties.aspx)

Comment: and what about associations? from what I've learned, they are lazy-loaded by default?

Comment: Yes, they are loaded in lazy manner by default: http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-mapping